# searching JSON object with indexOf returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON objects of chat messages in messages.json, as seen below:

```
[
  {
   "sender": "Bob",
   "text": "Hi, how are you?"
  },
  {
   "sender": "James",
   "text": "Good, you?"
  }
]
```

I want to search messages for the index of a term received from a text input. However when I run the following code, I receive "undefined" in the console.

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  const result = messages.filter((message) => {
    return message.text.indexOf(event.target.value);
  });
  console.log(result);
};
```

Why is it returning undefined?

Comment: Hint: `{} !== {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf()` returns 0 based index so you need to convert it to `boolean` to avoid false positives. Also `event.target.value` might be empty, or has a different case.

I recommend making sure both values are defined and converting both strings to same case `toLowerCase()` before comparison

```js
const messages = [{
    "sender": "Bob",
    "text": "Hi, how are you?"
  },
  {
    "sender": "James",
    "text": "Good, you?"
  }
]

const result = messages.filter((message) => {
  return message.text.toLowerCase().indexOf("good") >= 0;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

indexOf returns 0 if it found at the first character, which evaluates to FALSE. Try it with

```
return message.text.indexOf(event.target.value) > -1
```

Comment: More importantly, indexOf returns `-1` when the text is _not found_, and `-1` evaluates to `true`, so the filter includes messages where the text is not found or is found, as long as it wasn't found at 0

Answer (score -1):

Since  message is array, indexOf won't work, you need to iterate to find single msg, use find() for that, to find multiple instances use filter()

```
   const handleChange = (event) => {
          const result = message.find(i=>i.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()));
          console.log(result);
        };
```